# SpringBoot 2.1 spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

We are upgrading to SpringBoot 2.1.x and Spring Security 5.1.x.  We have our own SecurityConfig that overrides springSecurityFilterChain bean that is found in  org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.  I have added that property to the applications.property file and set it to true but it is still not allowing overrides.

Our class:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain() throws Exception {
    blahblahblah
    }
}
```

And the Spring class:

```
package org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration implements ImportAware, BeanClassLoaderAware {

    @Bean(
    name = {"springSecurityFilterChain"}
    )
    public Filter springSecurityFilterChain() throws Exception {
         blahblah
    }
}
```

The error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource
```

Its not clear to me why setting the override property to true is not being picked up.  I have also tried to annotate our bean as primary, the @autoconfigureBefore(WebSecurityConfiguration.class) and removing non-wanted bean from registry (but haven't figured out how to do that successfully).  Is there something special about the bean I am trying to override that prevents it?  Do I need to have the applications.property file loaded earlier somehow?

Answer (score 1):

same issue here. what is the solution for this. I have

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ScheduledLockConfiguration taskScheduler(LockProvider lockProvider) {
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be invoked as another bean in third party library exists with same name.